# Need to change From Email Address in Email templates

Tags: workflow

I want to change From Email Address for emails.But it is showing only two options 
a)Default workflow user's email address
b)Current user's email address.

is there any other way i can change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure [Organization-Wide email addresses](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/orgwide_email.htm) that can be assigned for use by profile. That would provide another option.